# Life of a bulb in probability

Tags: probability

The probability that an electric bulb will last $150$ days or more is $0.7$ and that it will last at most $160$ is $0.8$ . What is The probability that the bulb will last between $150$ to $160$ days ?

I understand that these two events are dependent because the bulb can last $160$ days only if the bulb lasts atleast $150$ days .

So if we let

$A$ = probability that the bulb lasts 150 days or more

$B$ =probability that the bulb lasts 160 days or less

We can write

$P(A\cap B)= P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$

I got to this point , however to get the solution it is required that we take $P(A\cup B)=1$.

I’m not able to reason it out. I’m not sure whether  it should be one because it is not necessary that the bulb will *necessarily last* between $150$ and $160$ days since it may even last less than $150$ days . Can you please help me ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $t$ as the (random) time that the bulb lasts. We have by definition $t \ge 0$, or pedantically, $0 \le t < \infty$

Let me repeat how the **events** are defined:
\begin{align}
&A : \text{event that the bulb lasts 150 days or more} \\
&B : \text{event that the bulb lasts 160 days or less}
\end{align}

Thus formally
$$
\begin{aligned}
&A : t \ge 150 ~, &&\text{or} & 150 \le t &\le \infty \\
&B : t \le 160 ~, &&\text{or} & 0 \le t &\le 160 
\end{aligned} \implies \begin{aligned}
&A \cap B: 150 \le  t \le 160 \\
&A \cup B : 0 \le t \le \infty
\end{aligned} $$

The interval of event $A$ starts at $150$ and covers all the way to the right. Event $B$ covers up to $160$ and goes "all the way to the left" (to zero by definition).

Thus the union of $A$ and $B$ covers everything and $P(A \cup B) = 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Now I have understood it very clearly :)